# Parsing numbers and stdStrings to char* in C++ [QT]

Tags: c++, c, qt

I have this piece of code, where `audio_bitRate` & `video_bitRate` are numbers, and `audio_address` & `video_address` are strings.

I get these variables from my Qt interface, but I don't know what happens when I try to parse these variables to my `char *vector[10]`, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
int counter = 0;
char *vector[10];
memset(vector, 0, 10);
qDebug() << counter;
audio_address = ui->lineEdit->text().toStdString();
video_address = ui->lineEdit_2->text().toStdString();
audio_bitRate = ui->lineEdit_3->text().toDouble();
video_bitRate = ui->lineEdit_4->text().toDouble();
qDebug() << audio_bitRate;
qDebug() << video_bitRate;

pat_bitRate = ui->lineEdit_6->text().toDouble();
pmt_bitRate = ui->lineEdit_7->text().toDouble();
ewbs_bitRate = ui->lineEdit_8->text().toDouble();
qDebug() << "00";

//The problem is here

strcpy(vector[0], (char*)(&audio_bitRate));
strcpy(vector[1],(char*)(&audio_address));
strcpy(vector[2], (char*)(&video_bitRate));
strcpy(vector[3],(char*)(&video_address));
```

In this part my application finished, the exact message from the command line of QT is `

> "The program has unexpectedly finished."

Comment: `char *vector[10];` this is an array of pointers to `char`, but those pointers do not point anywhere.

Comment: what are `audio_bitRate` and `audio_adress` actually, because you probably shouldnt be doing this: `(char*)(&x)` to an `int` and certainly not to a `std::string`

Comment: @Ben according to the documentation, `.toStdString()` returns a `std::string` object , and `.toDouble()` returns the `string` converted to a `double` value. I defined the variables up in my code like this `using namespace std;
string audio_address; double audio_bitRate;
string video_address; double video_bitRate;`

Comment: @user657267 I use `memset(vector, 0, 10);` to initialize my vector but, I have the same error.

Comment: @Ita Now you have an array of null pointers. Are you sure you understand how pointers and `char` strings work?

Comment: @Ita do you want to show your intentions for this array of strings and numbers. I feel like you would be better off with 2 `std::vectors` or a `map`

Comment: @user657267 I really don't know much.

@Ben what I want is to manipulate different types of variables, `int`, `chars` in other parts of the code in a simple way, the way I found to make this posible is to put this data in `vector` like strings(I mean `vector[0]` equal `number1`, `vector[1]` equal `char1`) and then change them to `double` to use them( in the case of `number1`)

Answer (score 0):

1) I can see that your not allocated memory for vector.

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int size = 10;  // allocate size how much you required
    vector[i] = (char*) malloc(size);
    memset(vector[i], 0, size);
}
```

2) For converting number in QString to char * you can use bellow code:

Example:

```
strcpy(vector[1], ui->lineEdit_3->text().toStdString().c_str());
```

Note: For converting number to byte array you need to use different method.